# Laravel Save And Show Image From Database

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Laravel Problem:
how can store and show image to/from database.
Can help me how to solve it?

Here is my code:

Store code:

```
public function store(FormRequest $request)
    {

        $slug = uniqid();
        $item = new Item(array(
            'title' => $request->get('title'),
            'image' => $request->get('image'),
            'content' => $request->get('content'),

        ));

        $item->save();

    }
```

Show code:

```
    @foreach($items as $item)
            <tr>
                   <td>{!! $item->id !!} </td>
                   <td>{!! $item->title !!}</td>
                   <td><img src="{{ asset($item->image) }}" /></td>

             </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot part of the code? All you're doing here is adding items to the database but you're not retrieving them anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You may use data-url by adding base64 encoded content into src as described in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

You could also add a route providing images for example by id.

Comment: how to use code become base64 encoded? can give example?

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Upload image coding   
// Get Form Image
             $image = $request->file('image');
            $slug = str_slug($request->name);
            if (isset($image))
            {
                $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
                $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                if (!file_exists('storage/uploads/post'))
                {
                    mkdir('storage/uploads/post',0777,true);
                }
                $image->move('storage/uploads/post',$imagename);
            }else{
                $imagename = "default.png";
            }
```

---

```
//getting coding


 public function index(){

    return view('admin.post.index',compact('posts'));
    }
```

---

```
// show code

<div class="body">
  <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="{{ asset('storage/uploads/post/'.$post->image) }}" >
    </div>
```